# What are the advantages of going through the practice league?

Tags: starcraft-2

What are the advantages of going through the practice league?  Aside from the practice and that battle.net can find better matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The practice league is usefull if you never played SC2 multiplayer. It uses `Novice maps` where the entrances to both main bases are blocked by destructible rocks which prevent you from being rushed and shuts down many cheesy builds like cannon rush. Through this you have some more time to build up and get used to your buildings and units until you engage with your opponent.
Although when you get out of the practice league you maybe will have to readjust your play since there no longer is any early game protection.

**IMO** its better go do some custom games vs AI or people you know to get used to multiplayer and the maps.

Comment: Also practice-leage runs on "Normal" game-speed if I recall correctly. So the game runs a bit slower. Good for getting started, but it's a noticeable change when the game suddenly runs on "Faster" in ladder.

Answer (score 2):

if you are aiming to get all the achievements then its a good time to get allot of the LEAGUE COMBAT achievements, other than that only thing i can think of is learning the different buildings, but you can do that vs AI anyway